# Python - Create album with Picasa Error

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, picasa

Google have recently shifted to OAuth2.0 and we need to change our previous auth macanisms (i.e. from `ProgrammaticLogin` to `OAuth2.0`).

I can successfully access the albums and read the data / comments on photos. Its when i try to add new album/photo or try to write data i get the following error.

```
    client = PhotosService(email="xxxx")    
   ...
   ...
   ...
   #After successfull OAuth 
   album = client.InsertAlbum(title="Temp album", summary="My summary", access="public")
```

This line causing the following error.

```
  File "/Users/mac/destipak/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gdata/photos/service.py", line 358, in InsertAlbum
    raise GooglePhotosException(e.args[0])
gdata.photos.service.GooglePhotosException: (403, 'Forbidden', 'Modification only allowed with api authentication.')
```

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't quite sure but did you actually make the change over OAuth2?  I used the following code and it worked.

```
def OAuth2Login(client_secrets, credential_store, email):
scope='https://picasaweb.google.com/data/'
user_agent='testingApp'

storage = Storage(credential_store)
credentials = storage.get()
if credentials is None or credentials.invalid:
    flow = flow_from_clientsecrets(client_secrets, scope=scope, redirect_uri='urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob')
    uri = flow.step1_get_authorize_url()
    webbrowser.open(uri)
    code = raw_input('Enter the authentication code: ').strip()
    credentials = flow.step2_exchange(code)
    storage.put(credentials)

if (credentials.token_expiry - datetime.utcnow()) < timedelta(minutes=5):
    http = httplib2.Http()
    http = credentials.authorize(http)
    credentials.refresh(http)

gd_client = gdata.photos.service.PhotosService(source=user_agent,
                                           email=email,
                                           additional_headers={'Authorization' : 'Bearer %s' % credentials.access_token})

return gd_client
album = gd_client.InsertAlbum('test', 'My Test Album', access='protected')
```

I did have to create an API Key in the Google developer portal and download the json secret but after doing that I was able to create an album successfully.  This repo was very helpful https://github.com/MicOestergaard/picasawebuploader.